# What could be causing RequestMappingHandlerMapping to not register correctly?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to register a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` instance though no matter what I do it doesn't get executed.

I've tried copying [the example from the spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) with no luck.

Could it be that `<annotation-driven>` is doing something that could be preventing my interceptor from being registered?

I tried removing the id from `handlerMapping` though that only caused spring to register two instances in the container.

I've tried registering in both the root context and the servlet context.

**Full servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

  <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
  <annotation-driven/>

  <beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="interceptors">
      <beans:list>
        <beans:ref bean="officeHoursInterceptor"/>
      </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>
  <beans:bean id="officeHoursInterceptor"
        class="com.johnsands.web.servlet.TimeBasedAccessInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="openingTime" value="9"/>
    <beans:property name="closingTime" value="18"/>
  </beans:bean>

  <!-- ReST Exception Handling
       http://www.stormpath.com/blog/spring-mvc-rest-exception-handling-best-practices-part-1
       -->
  <beans:bean id="restExceptionResolver"
              class="com.stormpath.spring.web.servlet.handler.RestExceptionHandler">
    <beans:property name="order" value="100"/>
    <beans:property name="errorConverter">
      <beans:bean class="com.johnsands.spring.web.servlet.handler.BasicRestErrorConverter"/>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="errorResolver">
      <beans:bean class="com.stormpath.spring.web.servlet.handler.DefaultRestErrorResolver">
        <beans:property name="localeResolver" ref="localeResolver"/>
        <beans:property name="defaultMoreInfoUrl" value="mailto:support@mycompany.com"/>
        <beans:property name="exceptionMappingDefinitions">
          <beans:map>
            <!-- 404 -->
            <beans:entry key="com.johnsands.api.ResourceNotFoundException" value="404, _exmsg"/>

            <!-- 500 (catch all): -->
            <beans:entry key="Throwable" value="500"/>
          </beans:map>
        </beans:property>
      </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver"/>

  <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /static/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/static/ directory -->
  <resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />

  <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </beans:bean>

  <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
  <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

</beans:beans>
```

controllers.xml doesn't do much

```
<!-- Maps '/' requests to the 'home' view -->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" view-name="login" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/logout" view-name="logout" />

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.johnsands" />
```

Handler is as follows:

```
public class TimeBasedAccessInterceptor
        extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger log =
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(TimeBasedAccessInterceptor.class);
    private int openingTime;
    private int closingTime;

    public TimeBasedAccessInterceptor() {
        log.info(" *** Constructing Instance *** ");
    }

    public void setOpeningTime(int openingTime) {
        this.openingTime = openingTime;
    }

    public void setClosingTime(int closingTime) {
        this.closingTime = closingTime;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {
        log.info(" *** (preHandle) *** ");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        if (openingTime <= hour && hour < closingTime) {
            return true;
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com.au");
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response,
                           Object handler,
                           ModelAndView modelAndView)
            throws Exception {
        log.info(" *** (postHandle) *** ");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response,
                                Object handler,
                                Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        log.info(" *** (afterCompletion) *** ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you include your Spring context configuration file and the handler implementation class if it isn't too large?

Comment: Brett, you have very good reputation. No one on SO expects incomplete questions from you.. edit question and provide configuration file.

Comment: Have now included my full configuration.

Comment: @Nandkumar, I do apologise, no excuses but it's 4am here and I'm lacking.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you are right about `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` overriding the RequestMappingHandlerMapping that you have created with the custom interceptor registered through it. The way to register the interceptor is instead with a `<mvc:interceptors..>`:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class=".."/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Or if you want it at a specific mapping:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/test"/>
        <bean class="test"></bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

If you want an explicit `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, then you will also need to define the HandlerAdapter to go with it and remove `mvc:annotation-driven`

Comment: That's done the job brilliantly, I thank you very much for this. It's also a lot less verbose this way too. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Biju could you point me in the direction for where this feature is documented? I couldn't find it in the [most recent spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor).

Comment: Here it is Brett - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors

Comment: Oh my I feel silly now, I just opened that and realised I had the exact page sitting in front of me but didn't see that. Thank you once again.